# JQuery click slidetoggle only working for the first DIV of PHP repeated DIVS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have DIVs which are repeated for records in a database via PHP, and I have jquery script which on click should expand a div bellow out.

This is  the simple code for the slide, generic stuff:

```
<script src =
  "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script> 
  $(document).ready(function(){        // Line A   
    $("#flip").click(function(){       // Line B
      $("#panel").slideToggle("slow"); // Line C
    });
  });
</script>


<body>

  <div style="background:red" id="flip">Click to slide the panel down or up</div>

  <div style="background:green" id="panel">Oh Hello There</div>


#panel {
    display:none;
    }
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hpvgp/3/

However when I try and apply this to my code where I have the divs looped out, it only works for the first div.

Current code:

```
<?php
$webserver = 'localhost'; 
$administrator = 'root';
$password = '';
$db_name = 'cdb';
$db = mysqli_connect($webserver, $administrator, $password, $db_name)
  or die('Error connecting');

if( isset($_REQUEST['page'])) {
  $_SESSION['page'] = $_REQUEST['page'];
}else{
  $_SESSION['page'] = 1;
}
$records_per_page = 8;
$query = "SELECT * FROM cars";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query)
  or die("Error in query: '$query'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$i = 0;
$start = ($_SESSION['page'] - 1) * $records_per_page;
$end = ($_SESSION['page']) * $records_per_page;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) and $i < $end) {
  $i++;
  if( $i > $start ) 
  {;
    echo'
    <div><br><br>

      <div id="flip" class="navbar navbar-inverse" style ="margin-top:-40px; height:128px"> 

          <div style="float:left; height:100px; width:200px">
            <img src="'.$row['logo'].'" style="margin:10px; float:left" height="100"/></div> 
            <div style="float:left"><h2>'.$row['make'].' '.$row['model'].'</h2></div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div><img id="panel" style="padding-bottom: 100px" src="images/cars/'.$row['carIndex'].'.jpg" height="300"/><div> ';
  }
}
```

I'm currently using Bootstrap, not sure if that would matter.

I find it really strange that this would work for the first DIV but not any of the following ones. Do I perhaps need to place the script somewhere else? I'm really lost on this.

Any help appreciated -Tom

Comment: ID's are unique, so jQuery is expecting only one single element with that ID, so it only works on the first one. Use classes instead.

Comment: Use class instead of id on divs

Comment: Ah yes, changing it to class instead of id now makes it work for all, but it literally applies to all, I click on 1 and they all expand, I think I'll need to use accordion. Though I tried it earlier and accordion didn't wanna work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDs are expected to be unique. Never use the same id more than once in a document. Change your code to:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) and $i < $end) {
    $i++;
    if( $i > $start ) 
    {
        echo'
          <div><br><br>

               <div class="flip navbar navbar-inverse" data-panel="panel_' + $i . '" style ="margin-top:-40px; height:128px"> 

                <div style="float:left; height:100px; width:200px">
                    <img src="'.$row['logo'].'" style="margin:10px; float:left" height="100"/></div> 
                <div style="float:left"><h2>'.$row['make'].' '.$row['model'].'</h2></div>
               </div>
         </div>

         <div><img id="panel_' . $i . '" style="padding-bottom: 100px" src="images/cars/'.$row['carIndex'].'.jpg" height="300"/><div> ';
    }
}
```

And now chang your javascript to:

```
<script> 
  $(document).ready(function(){          
    $(".flip").click(function(){  
      var panelId = $(this).attr('data-panel');   
      $('#' + panelId).slideToggle("slow")
    });
  });
</script>
```

This way your IDs are unique, and each panel is related to its 'flip' div via a custom attribute (`data-panel`) that contains the panel's ID.

Comment: I just twigged this solution, but yours is smoother, I placed the script in the echo with the loop number added on to the js class name.

Answer (score 1):

You're assigning the same ID to multiple divs.  An ID is, by definition, unique.  If you set the same ID on more than one element then your HTML will be invalid and all bets are off.  jQuery will use GetElementByID () to select which element to grab when you pass it an ID, and the behaviour of GetElementByID when there's more than one element with the same ID is undefined.  It could in theory do anything (throw an exception, return the first matching element, select the last matching element, select a single matching element at random, make demons fly out of your nose, etc).

As you want your code to affect more than one element, then all those elements have something in common.  Therefore they all belong to the same class of elements, and you should use class="someclass" to indicate which elements belong to that class.  HTML like:

```
<div class="flip navbar navbar-inverse" style ="margin-top:-40px; height:128px">
```

JS like:

```
$(".flip").click(function(){       // Line B
```

Answer (score 0):

As an advice that works at least for me, when I'm using classes for bind functions, I like to difference that class to the others, so I add the prefix "js-" to the class. That way I'll know that it's not a design class, that an event is bind to that class and that class should not be removed. So I'll use "js-flip" instead "flip". But it is just and advice as good practises and some people cannot be agree with me, but it has been quite useful in projects where more than one person were touching the same code. Also I will not add css styles to that class because the porpoise of it is only programmatic, so it will be transparent for the designers.